# grey-out button when top level window is opened

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hey I am using Tkinter Python and I have a name entry.

If an invalid name is entered it will come up with a error in a new window. I want the original window or button to be greyed out while this error is open, and then go back to normal once it is closed. Is this possible? I don't want the button to be spammed and open multiple error boxes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ux23.png)

Comment: You can use `tkinter.messagebox.showerror()` which will disable the parent window when it is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you 2 approaches to do that.

I would suggest using a `tkinter.messagebox` to show the error(or info ) to the user because it will disable the `root` window until it remains open. It plays sounds as per system preferences and allows pressing enter to close out the pop-up

Like this::

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgb   # use your preferred import style

def submit():
    if e.get() == 'something':  # check input here
        doSomething()
    else:
        msgb.ShowError('Invalid input', 'seems like you entered incorrect name')

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

2nd Approach:

If you really need to only use a Toplevel window and have to grey out entry box (and/or the button) - here is how

```
import tkinter as tk

def submit():
    if e.get() == 'something':  # check input here
        doSomething()
    else:
        e.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        btn.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        showSomethingHere()

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit)
e.pack()
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```